# uninstall silently in background using setup.exe

Tags: installshield, uninstallation

I want to uninstall a  software which is installed using EXE not MIS. By running the uninstall Strin in CMD i can able to uninstall but its asking conformation messages.

My intention is to uninstall it silently

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{2EA86967-B3D3-4B2E-9DE9-28A595AF2E2E}\setup.exe" -runfromtemp -l0x0409  -removeonly
```

I tried this command but its asking so many conformation messages for uninstall. Is there any attribute I can add here so that it will uninstall in background

Comment: You generally need to generate a silent response files for legacy Installshield stuff: [Installshield summary PDF](https://resources.flexera.com/web/pdf/archive/silent_installs.pdf). Have a look at the [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63224525/uninstall-a-program-using-bat-file#comment111802355_63224525).  Here is a random hit KDB article from IBM: [Is it possible to automate the uninstallation process for the OnDemand client?](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/it-possible-automate-uninstallation-process-ondemand-client)

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the setup with silent execution parameter as mentioned in the below article:
silent command line parameter: Setup.exe /s /v/qn
https://docs.flexera.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm